# using fs.readFile in NodeJS and setting utf8, there are still garbled codes

Tags: httpresponse, node.js-fs

I'm learning the fs module in nodeJS, and I have a problem when reading files with readFile. The same two pages have the same creation method, and the file reading format is set, but 404.html can respond correctly, and login.html has garbled. Can someone help me?

I tried to set the correct utf8 format, hoping to get the html page content correctly, but I still got the garbled code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYPUD.png)

Comment: You can try `res.sendFile('filepath/myimage.png');` - no need to read the file (in this case).

Comment: thanks,I'm new to NodeJS at present, and I want NodeJS to solve it, and I don't want to introduce the framework too early.

Comment: Thank you for your reply to this question.,The problem has been solved, and the company's encryption software caused abnormal file reading.